# ClassNotFoundException org.h2.Driver in Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to deploy and run my ear file in wildfly. when I try to access following code it gives ClassNotFoundException for org.h2.Driver.

```
String jdbcURL = "jdbc:h2:file;MODE=Derby;auto_server=true";            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username", "password");
```

My module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.h2database.h2">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="h2.jar"/>

    </resources>
    <dependencies>

        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

is any I need to Change?

Answer (score 0):

WildFly already ships with a module named `com.h2database.h2`. I don't think you need to add your own.

As for the `ClassNotFoundException`, make sure your deployment has a dependency on the module `com.h2database.h2`. There are several ways to add a dependency to your deployment the easiest probably being to add a `Dependencies: com.h2database.h2` to your `MANIFEST.MF`. See the [class loading documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) for other ways.

Comment: Yes. you are right. Wildfly by default loads H2 driver. but only one the case of Class.forName I m getting this exceptiom

Comment: Did you add a dependency for the module to your deployment?

Comment: I tried to add H2 module with jboss-deployment-structure.xml, but No luck.

Comment: It should definitely work if the dependency is in the correct place. If it's an EAR and your jboss-deployment-structure.xml is in your EAR/META-INF then make sure the sub-deployment that's using it has a dependency on it as well.